как переназначить стили рутуба?
возможно ли как-то переназначить стили css с рутуба, которые прописаны во внешнем css-файле?
суть в следующем.
у меня на сайт с рутуба embed'ом вставляются видео со своими стилями и скриптами. мне нужно изменить свойства превьюшки, которое обрезается на мобильных устройствах, т.е. мне нужно адаптировать превью видео, чтобы оно не обрезалось.
на первом скриншоте видно, что превью обрезано. в css это класс .raichu-wrapper-module__poster___fPYFZ и свойство object-fit: cover;

для того, чтобы превью отображалось правильно и не обрезалось, нужно object-fit: cover заменить на contain. в инспекторе кода я могу это сделать, и видно, что превью работает - второй скриншот:

а вот сам внешний css-файл рутуба - скриншот: выделил свойство, которое мне нужно принудительно изменить.
или ссылка на сам файл: https://rutube.ru/raichu-embed/style...78bc02f7f8.css

я пробовал переназначить стили у себя в файле стилей через !important и через jQuery, но не получилось. мои правки игнорируются браузером и код не меняется.
тп молчит - там всегда только бестолковый бот отвечает.
Спасибо заранее

Попробуйте "тестировать" не ресайзом. Возможно скрипты рутуба определяют размер вьюпорта при первой загрузке, а ресайз не поддерживается.

Нельзя. Именно для того, чтобы было нельзя, и придуман CORS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
https://habr.com/ru/companies/macloud/articles/553826/

